# Unable to connect to SQL Server Analysis Services using Azure Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, connection, ssas, hybrid, azure-sql-server

We have configured the Azure Hybrid Connection in the App Service which we want to access the SQL Server Analysis Services from On-Prem server.  The port configured in Hybrid Connection is 2383.  The connection status is showing connected on both the Azure and in the Hybrid Connection Manager of the On-Prem server.  But when we run the application it is throwing A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.

Comment: This is observed with TCP connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you might be having issue with TLS version that is currently enabled on your on-premises server. A detailed article on how to tackle each and every problem that you might be facing with the HCM can be found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6333521509524566016).

Hope this might be sufficient to solve all your problems.

Comment: Thank you @Tayyab.  Your article is helpful in configuring the Hybrid Connection.  We have configured the SSAS for Http Access (refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=sql-analysis-services-2017) and allowed the port 80 for Hybrid Connection.